# How to get rid of compiler errors in "A practical Template Haskell Tutorial"?

Tags: haskell

### Background

The tutorial "A practical Template Haskell Tutorial" provides some examples, which I wanted to play with. I just integrated one example into Lib.h, which has been generated by command `stack new`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.TH

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn "someFunc"

curryN :: Int -> Q Exp
curryN n = do
    f  <- newName "f"
    xs <- replicateM n (newName "x")
    let args = map VarP (f:xs)
        ntup = TupE (map VarE xs)
    return $ LamE args (AppE (VarE f) ntup)
```

The original source is here:
https://wiki.haskell.org/A_practical_Template_Haskell_Tutorial

### Problem

Unfortunalely, I get one compilation error and an hlint warning about the pragma.

Compilation error:

> • Couldn't match type ‘Exp’ with ‘Maybe Exp’   Expected: [Maybe Exp]
> Actual: [Exp]
>
> • In the first argument of ‘TupE’, namely ‘(map VarE xs)’   In the expression: TupE (map VarE xs)   In an equation for
> ‘ntup’: ntup = TupE (map VarE xs)

I tried to fix this and here is my try:

```
curryN :: Int -> Q Exp
curryN n = do
    f  <- newName "f"
    xs <- replicateM n (newName "x")
    let args = map VarP (f:xs)
        ntup = TupE (map VarE (Just xs))
    return $ LamE args (AppE (VarE f) ntup)
```

But, it did not work.

### Further Background: Impact

What is the impact on the Haskell comunity when we have such examples?

I am studying this language without any help - except the SO comunity. Without SO I would have given up long time ago. However, for myself it is still very cumbersome to catch up with the long history of Haskell, it's flaws in libraries, chaos by neccessary changes, and weakness of documentation.

Such examples are tiring - for me. What do you think? Please, leve a comment.

### Question(s)

How solve this in general?

Why do we have tutorials without complete and working code?

First guess: The compiler plattform, libraries and tools have been changed after creating the tutorial but nobody checked whether the tutorials are still inline.

Especially: How would the curryN function look like after correction?

Comment: The "Impact" and "Why do we have bad tutorials" questions are not really on topic for Stack Overflow. My brief answer to "bad tutorials", though, is: this is inevitable for any documentation that isn't part of a language's release process. Whoever maintains the language doesn't know what tutorials they're breaking, and often couldn't fix the tutorials even if they did know. Whoever maintains the tutorial doesn't keep up perfectly (perhaps at all?) with language changes. Thus, they drift.

Comment: @amalloy Yes, I guess so too. And yes I know, some off topic, and influencial questions are in there. Thank you for sharing your opinion.

Comment: @amalloy I just requested to get access to the Haskell wiki. At least, I will try to contribute a bit for known solutions of known problems in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

See the code below.

It works warning free, using `-Wall`, hlint free, and providing the expected result, as soon as you put the template code into a seperate module, change the code using the combinator `.` (see `(Just . VarE)`), and leave the pragma in the main code to apply the `$`.

File: Curry.hs

```
module Curry
    (
        curryN
    ) where

import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.TH

curryN :: Int -> Q Exp
curryN n = do
    f  <- newName "f"
    xs <- replicateM n (newName "x")
    let args = map VarP (f:xs)
        ntup = TupE (map (pure . VarE) xs)
    return $ LamE args (AppE (VarE f) ntup)
```

File: Lib.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import Curry

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = 
    do
        print $ $(curryN 3) f1 1 ' ' ["Hallo"]
        print $ $(curryN 3) f1 1 ' ' ["Hallo","World"]
        print $ $(curryN 3) f1 1 ' ' ["Hallo","World","!"]

f1 :: (Int,Char,[String]) -> String
f1 (ni,ch,[]) = []
f1 (ni,ch,[s0]) = s0
f1 (ni,ch,s0:s1:rls) = s0 ++ replicate ni ch ++ f1 (ni,ch,s1:rls)
```

Prints:

```
"Hallo"
"Hallo World"
"Hallo World !"
```

Regarding the other questions:

Comment: For what it's worth, [the documentation for `TupE`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.18.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:TupE) notes that the `Maybe`s are required to handle tuple sections. So I guess the old version of TH didn't let you emit `(x,)`, and the modern one does, but that API required rewrites at the call site which weren't done for this tutorial. I agree that your `(Just . VarE)` is the right fix. You could equivalently write `(pure . VarE)` which might be more forward-compatible?

Comment: @amalloy Thank you. I changed the answer accordingly.